# HQL with where clause with join doesn't work

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, hql

`Hi, I'm beginner to hibernate and I have to make a select with join. I have two classes Employees and Departments mapped one-to-one, bidirectional that look like this:

```
     @Entity(name="employee")
     @Table(name="employee")
     public class Employees {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="employee_id")
Integer employeeNumber;
@Column(name="full_name")
String fullName;
@Column(name="email_address")
String emailAddress;
@Column(name="phone_number")
long phoneNumber;
@Column(name="birth_date")
Date birthDate;
@Column(name="gender")
String gender;
@Column(name="address")
String address;
@Column(name="country")
String country;
@Column(name="city")
String city;
@Column(name="region")
String region;
@Column(name="post_code")
String postCode;
@Column(name="hire_date")
Date hireDate;
@Column(name="resignation_date")
Date resignationDate;
@Column(name="position")
String position;
@Column(name="cnp_pin")
String cnp;
@Column(name="document_no")
Integer documentNumber;
@Column(name="expire_doc_no")
Date expireDocument;

 @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
 @JoinColumn(name="department_id")
Departments department;



@Entity(name="department")
@Table(name="department")
public class Departments {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="department_id")
int departmentId;
@Column(name="department_name")
String departmentName;
@Column(name="leader")
String leader;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="department")
Employees employee;
```

I tried this:

```
@Test
public List<Employees> listEmployee() {
       session.beginTransaction();
      List<Employees> employee = (List<Employees>) session.createQuery("select         e.employeeNumber, e.fullName, d.departmentName from  employee e JOIN department d where e.department=d.departmentId").getResultList();
for(Employees emp:employee) {
System.out.println(emp);
    }
    return employee;

}
```

I want to select employeeNumber, fullName and departmentName with JOIN between tables but I have this         error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where employees0_.department_id=department1_.department_id' at line 1. Can You help me please?`

Comment: `...FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.cx = t2.cy...`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.employeeNumber, 
       e.fullName, 
       d.departmentName 
FROM  
       Employee e 
JOIN   Department d where e.department=d.departmentId").getResultList();
```

"HQL queries are case insensitive; however, the names of Java classes and properties are case-sensitive HQL is used to execute queries against database."

Comment: After editing I get the following error:  java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class com.danycode.hibernate.entity.Employees ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.danycode.hibernate.entity.Employees is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @7c351808)